# Help! I wiped out my /boot/efi partition. How to recover?

Tags: data-recovery

I made a foolish mistake and copied an *img file over my /boot/efi partition instead of an SD card.

```
System:
Dell XPS15
Kubuntu 19.10
1 TB SSD
```

My system was set up to multiboot Kubuntu 19.10, Kubuntu 20.04, and Windows 10.
I made a copy of my 'disk' to an external USB drive to analyze.

I've tried examining the disk using testdisk and it was able to see the partition information:

```
Current partition structure:
Bad GPT partition, invalid signature.
Trying alternate GPT
 1 P EFI System                  2048    1026047    1024000 [EFI system partition]
No FAT, NTFS, ext2, JFS, Reiser, cramfs or XFS marker
 2 P MS Reserved              1026048    1288191     262144 [Microsoft reserved partition]
 2 P MS Reserved              1026048    1288191     262144 [Microsoft reserved partition]
No FAT, NTFS, ext2, JFS, Reiser, cramfs or XFS marker
 3 P MS Data                  1288192  206043135  204754944 [Basic data partition]
 3 P MS Data                  1288192  206043135  204754944 [Basic data partition]
 4 P Linux filesys. data    206043136  245104639   39061504
 5 P Linux filesys. data    245104640  284165186   39060547
 6 P Linux filesys. data    284166144 1973938175 1689772032
 7 P Windows Recovery Env  1974859776 1998145535   23285760
 8 P Windows Recovery Env  1998145536 2000408575    2263040
Backup partition structure
```

The partition information looks correct to me. At this point I'm not sure what I should do try recovering my drive. Which tools should I use? I've obviously looked at testdisk. Would ddrescue  be able to help?

The file I was copying was about 500 MB and I (inadvertantly) copied it over the first partition of the drive. 
Although I'm a long-time Linux user, I've never had to do disk recovery before. Other than making a full backup of the drive using dd and running testdisk to look at the drive, I have not made any changes to it yet. What are my next steps? What tools should I use?

I'd really like to at least recover my data partition (partition 6 in the table above).

Thanks for any assistance.

[edit to add:]
I tried listing files in testdisk for each of the partitions without any success (no files found).

I tried running gdisk. It did not see the partitions. The output is below:

```
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdb
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

Caution: invalid main GPT header, but valid backup; regenerating main header
from backup!

Warning: Invalid CRC on main header data; loaded backup partition table.
Warning! Main and backup partition tables differ! Use the 'c' and 'e' options
on the recovery & transformation menu to examine the two tables.

Warning! Main partition table CRC mismatch! Loaded backup partition table
instead of main partition table!

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!
Main header: ERROR
Backup header: OK
Main partition table: ERROR
Backup partition table: OK

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

Found valid MBR and corrupt GPT. Which do you want to use? (Using the
GPT MAY permit recovery of GPT data.)
 1 - MBR
 2 - GPT
 3 - Create blank GPT

Your answer: 2

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 3906963456 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Model: My Passport 25E1
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 91626CE4-3C38-4BF1-A7DD-0B4FA3BC3A15
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3906963422
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 4029 sectors (2.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      3906961407   1.8 TiB     0700  My Passport
```

It just sees the entire drive.

Comment: Just a comment for those that are traumatized by this question read this: [How can I make a backup of an EFI System partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698980/how-can-i-make-a-backup-of-an-efi-system-partition)

Comment: Try some of these, they might help: https://www.ubuntupit.com/top-15-linux-data-recovery-tools-the-professionals-choice/

Comment: If you only damaged primary partition, perhaps gpt's backup is ok? Try gdisk. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html or try parted rescue, since you have good idea of start & end sectors which is required for parted rescue. Parted rescue seems easier than testdisk
https://askubuntu.com/questions/665445/upgraded-to-windows-10-on-dual-boot-and-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-partition