# How to copy and restore to smaller partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, software-recommendation, ext4, clone

I want to copy a partition from hd to another with small partition.

#### Must be:

- support ext4 file system
- can create image file for later use.
- compress images files
- copy only the used file system
- restore to smaller and bigger partition in destination hd

#### Optional:

- Have network connection to one of the following protocol: ftp, sftp, ftps, webdad nfs
- support other file system: ntfs, fat32, ext3, ext2
- has a gui

---

I already see this questions and answer,
but my question is more specific, and no good answers that help me.
other topic i already see:
[How to clone to a smaller harddisk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409204/how-to-clone-to-a-smaller-harddisk)
[Cloning hard disk partition to smaller SSD on laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842029/cloning-hard-disk-partition-to-smaller-ssd-on-laptop)
[Clone internal HDD to new SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118927/clone-internal-hdd-to-new-ssd)

Comment: Use `rsync` ...

Comment: Can `rsync` create a compress image file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best solution for me is here:
boot with live cd with ubuntu 18-04.
enable "Universe" repository:
[image]
install sshfs: `sudo apt-get install sshfs`
`sshfs` if you want to save or restore from remote server that has sftp protocol.
install qt5-fsarchiver from here:
[qt5-fsarchiver](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qt4-fsarchiver/files/qt5-fsarchiver/deb-Pakete/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2018.04%20Bionic/).
The project call qt4-fsarchiver.
fsarchiver has all the must thing i need:
[FSArchiver ability](http://www.fsarchiver.org/partimage/)

#### Must be:

- "Ability to save/restore new generation linux filesystems (ext4, reiser4, btrfs)"
- "Ability to restore the filesystem to a partition which is smaller than the original"
- "Ability to restore the filesystem to a partition which is bigger than the original"
- "Compression algorithms which are supported"

The optional stuff came from qt4-fsarchiver project and ubuntu live cd:

#### Optional:

- qt4-fsarchiver has gui.
- ubuntu nautilus has [network connection](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/nautilus-connect.html.en): ftp, ftps, sftp, nfs, webdav.
  (it was hard for me that qt5-fsarchiver will find the virtual folder of sftp or ftps, so i use sshfs)
- use sshfs for mount sftp remote server
- fsarchiver also support ext2, ext3, fat32, ntfs:
  "Ability to save/restore standard linux filesystems (ext2, ext3, reiserfs, xfs, jfs)"
  "Ability to save/restore windows ntfs filesystems"